# Need to return value based on 3 criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

Looking for a formula that will return a # value in an array based on 3 criteria spread out between 2 spreadsheets: Account code, Line Description & Date.

Here is what it looks like:

Sheet 1:

```
Column A        Column B      Column C    Column D
Account #     Description       Date     (Enter formula here)
```

Sheet 2:

```
              Column A         Column I     -    Column AA
    Row 1    Account #       Description   -      Jan          Feb
             x                  x                  $            $
             x                  x                  $            $
                                                   $            $
                                                   $            $ 
                                                   $            $
                                                   $            $
```

I want the formula to return the Dollar amount in Columns AA on as long as the Account #'s, Item Description and Date match.

Here's a picture of what "spreadsheet 2" would look like. 
Column A is the Account #, Column I is the Item Description, And columns Z-AI are monthly $.

Also attached is a picture of spreadsheet 1 aka the spread sheet I want my data returned

So basically I want to return the monthly $ value if the Account #, Description and Date match

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Multiple criteria Index/Match might should work.

Comment: Welcome, Nathaniel! Can you please clarify your question? Right now it is difficult to determine for what *exactly* you're looking. Dummy data and/or expected results would definitely help users understand your question and hopefully provide appropriate assistance.

Comment: Of course! So I HAVE tried to create a Index Match function but maybe I was going about it wrong? The issue I was having is that the date rows are horizontal and I'm not exactly sure how to get around that issue. To clarify I want a $ number returned if the criteria (Item description, Date, and Account numbers) is met.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This solution should work. The data is in columns A:D, and my criteria for lookup is in J:L. Formula in M is:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1,INDEX((A:A=J2)*(B:B=K2)*(C:C=L2),0,1),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a VLOOKUP array function that will work for n columns and contains all the flexibility of an INDEX MATCH.

[image]